# Unexpected syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

given the following code from my custom model:

```
  def categorize
    @cv = Cv.find(params[:cv_id], :include => [:desired_occupations, :past_occupations, :educational_skills])
    @menu = :second
    @language = Language.resolve(:code => :en, :name => :en)
    categorizer = CvCategorizer.new @cv, @language
    categorizer.prepare_occupations
    categorizer.prepare_occupation_skills
    categorizer.prepare_education_skills

    # fetch the data
    @occupation_hashes = categorizer.occupations
    @skill_hashes = categorizer.skills

    # Sort the hashes
    @occupation_hashes.sort! { |x,y| y.score <=> x.score}
    @skill_hashes.sort! { |x,y| y.score <=> x.score}
    @max = @skill_hashes.first.score
    @min = @skill_hashes.last.score
  end
```

The code creates a new instance of the CvCategorizer class and calls the three prepare methods in sequence. They all do funky stuff with data retrieved from the database. The code looks as follows:

```
# = CvCategorizer
# This class will handle the categorizing of a CV based upon the skills and occupations found in
# the CV. Because the controller originally had a huge chunk of code, this class will break up that
# login into seperate function calls and keep everything inside variables for easy access.
class CvCategorizer
  # initializes a new instance of the CvCategorizer
  def initialize cv, language
    @cv = cv
    @language = language
    @occupations = []
    @skills = []
  end

  # Prepares the occupation array by looking at the stored CV and collecting
  # all the desired occupations and past occupations. These are stored inside
  # the internal occupation array as a uniq list.
  def prepare_occupations
    all_occupations = @cv.desired_occupations.all(:include => :labels) + @cv.past_occupations.all(:include => :labels)
    all_occupations.each do |occupation|
      oc = OccupationCategory.new
      oc.is_desired_work?= @cv.desired_occupations.include?(occupation)
      oc.is_work_experience?= @cv.past_occupations.include?(occupation)
      oc.occupation = occupation

      if !@occupations.include?(oc)
        @occupations << oc
      else
        obj = @occupations.select(oc)
        obj.score += 1
        obj.occupations= (obj.occupations & oc).uniq
      end
    end
=begin
    all_occupations = @cv.desired_occupations.all(:include => :labels) + @cv.past_occupations.all(:include => :labels)
    all_occupations.each do |occupation|
      section = []
      section << "Desired Work" if @cv.desired_occupations.include? occupation
      section << "Work experience" if @cv.past_occupations.include? occupation

      unless (array = @occupations.assoc(occupation)).blank?
        array[1]+= 1
        array[2] = (array[2] & section).uniq
      else
        @occupations << [occupation, 1, section, []]
      end
    end
=end
  end

  # Prepares the occupation skills of the CV by looping over all the stored
  # occupations and retrieving the skills for them and storing them in the
  # skills array.
  def prepare_occupation_skills
    # Loop over all the OccupationCategory objects currently present in the Categorizer.
    @occupations.each do |oc|
      # For each OccupationCategory object, retrieve all the associated skills, and
      # include their label as well.
      oc.occupation.skills.all(:include => :labels).each do |skill|
        # Get the label of the current concept we're working with.
        label = oc.occupation.concept.label(@language).value
        # Check if the @skills array already contains a SkillCategory object with the
        # skill we're currently checking.
        if (sc = @skills.select{|scs| scs.skill == skill}).blank?
          # The skill was not found, so create a new entry with the SkillCategory class and set the
          # correct values for the various properties
          sc = SkillCategory.new
          sc.labels << label
          sc.score= 1
          sc.is_occupation_skill? = true
          sc.skill= skill
        else
          # The skill was found in one of the SkillCategory objects. So we update the score by
          # 1 and store the label of the current concept, unless that label is already present.
          sc.labels << label unless sc.labels.include?(label)
          sc.is_occupation_skill?= true
          sc.score+= 1
        end
      end
    end
=begin
    @occupations.each do |array|
      array[0].skills.all(:include => :labels).each do |skill|
        unless (skill_array = @skills.assoc skill).blank?
          label = array[0].concept.label(@language).value
          skill_array[1]+= 1
          skill_array[3] << label unless skill_array[3].include? label
        else
          @skills << [skill, 1, [], [array[0].concept.label(@language).value]]
        end
      end
    end
=end
  end

  # Prepares the education skills by checking the CV and adding them to the
  # skills array
  def prepare_education_skills
    # Loop over all the educational skills that are currently associated to the CV.
    @cv.educational_skills.all(:include => :labels).each do |skill|
      # Check if the @skills array already contains a SkillCategory object with the
      # skill we're currently checking.
      if (sc = @skills.select{|scs| scs.skill == skill}).blank?
        # The skill was not found, so create a new entry with the SkillCategory class and set the
        # correct values for the various properties
        sc = SkillCategory.new
        sc.labels << 'Education skills' unless sc.labels.include?('Education skills')
        sc.score= 1
        sc.is_educational_skill?= true
        sc.skill= skill
      else
        # The skill was found in one of the SkillCategory objects. So we update the score by
        # 1 and store the label of the current concept, unless that label is already present.
        sc.labels << 'Education skills' unless sc.labels.include?('Education skills')
        sc.is_educational_skill?= true
        sc.score+= 1
      end
    end
=begin
    @cv.educational_skills.all(:include => :labels).each do |skill|
      unless (array = @skills.assoc skill).blank?
        array[1]+= 1
        array[3] << 'Education skills' unless array[3].include? 'Education skills'
      else
        @skills << [skill, 1, ['Education skills'], []]
      end
    end
=end
  end

  # Returns all uniq skills with their score and section found.
  # array structure for each element
  # - 0 : the skill object
  # - 1 : the score for the skill
  # - 2 : CV location of the skill
  # - 3 : ESCO group of the skill
  def skills
    @skills
  end

  # Returns all uniq occupations with their score and section found.
  # array structure for each element
  # - 0 : the occupation object
  # - 1 : the score for the occupation
  # - 2 : the CV location of the occupation
  # - 3 : empty array for occupations
  def occupations
    @occupations
  end
end
```

When browsing to the relevant view in the application, i'm receiving the following error message from the server:

> /home/arne.de.herdt/RubymineProjects/ESCO/app/models/cv_categorizer.rb:21:
>   syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting kEND
>         oc.is_desired_work?= @cv.desired_occupations.include?(...
>                                 ^
>   /home/arne.de.herdt/RubymineProjects/ESCO/app/models/cv_categorizer.rb:22:
>   syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting kEND ...
>   oc.is_work_experience?= @cv.past_occupations.include?(occ...
>                                 ^
>   /home/arne.de.herdt/RubymineProjects/ESCO/app/models/cv_categorizer.rb:69:
>   syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting kEND
>             sc.is_occupation_skill? = true
>                                      ^
>   /home/arne.de.herdt/RubymineProjects/ESCO/app/models/cv_categorizer.rb:75:
>   syntax error, unexpected kTRUE, expecting kEND
>   /home/arne.de.herdt/RubymineProjects/ESCO/app/models/cv_categorizer.rb:108:
>   syntax error, unexpected kTRUE, expecting kEND
>   /home/arne.de.herdt/RubymineProjects/ESCO/app/models/cv_categorizer.rb:114:
>   syntax error, unexpected kTRUE, expecting kEND

It seems I'm missing something in the CvCategorize class, but I can't find the stuff missing. The IDE is not showing errors such as missing ends or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the question marks on oc.is_desired_work? and oc.is_work_experience? on lines 21 and 22.

Comment: @neko - You have other locations in your code where you are missing spaces between the assignment operator. Assignment should always be `foo = bar`, not `foo= bar`. You will run into trouble using the latter. Check your code for these. Always use space on both sides of the assignment operator.

Comment: updated my code. But why does the ? cause problems? I mean the array class has an include? function, and I wanted the similar thing

Answer (score 1):

ruby allows the question marks in method names, not the variables ( of any kind ) or object attributes.

the ruby way would be to add instance methods to your OccupationCategory class, like so:

```
class OccupationCategory

  def is_desired_work?
    ...
  end

  def is_work_experience?
    ...
  end

end
```

so you could later use it like

```
oc.is_desired_work? 
oc.is_work_experience?
```